# symfony 3 ChoiceType ist not Valid

Tags: php, forms, symfony, symfony-3.2

i have a very easy script. It reads the ID and NAME from Table and add them as an option to my choiceType.

**SOLVED**
See last Script. you have to add all options in the form again.

This is the Action.

```
/**
 * @Route("/monitor/setup/carousel", name="SetupCarousel")
 */
public function SetupCarouselManageAction(Request $request){
    $repository = $this->getDoctrine()->getRepository("AppBundle:Picture");
    $pictures = $repository->findAll();
    $p = array();
    $p['-- Bitte Bild setzen'] = -1;
    foreach($pictures as $pic){
        $p[$pic->getTitle()] = $pic->getId();
    }
    $carousel = new Carousel();
    $FormCarousel = $this->createForm(CarouselType::class, $carousel, array(
            'pictures' => $p,
            'action' => $this->generateUrl('SetupInputCarousel')
    ));

    $render = $this->render('SetupCarousel.html.twig',array(
            'form_event' => $FormCarousel->createView()

    ));
    return $render;
}
```

The Form Type:

```
class CarouselType extends AbstractType{
public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options){

    $builder
        ->add("bildId", ChoiceType::class, 
                array('choices' => $options['pictures']))
        ->add('submit', SubmitType::class);
}
public function configureOptions(OptionsResolver $resolver)
{
    $resolver
    ->setDefaults(array(
            'data_class' => Carousel::class,
            'pictures'=> array('array')))
    ->setAllowedTypes('pictures', array('array'))
    ;
}
}
```

So far, so good. on my Page get the ChoiceType Box, i can select the entry i want and submit it. If i want to check if the data are valid it fails.

here my Entity

```
class Carousel{
/**
 * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
 * @ORM\Id
 * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
 */
protected $id;

/** @ORM\Column(type="integer") */
protected $bildId;

/**@ORM\Column(type="string") */
protected $text;
```

This is the way i get the data back at the moment.

```
/**
 * @Route("/monitor/setup/input/carousel",name="SetupInputCarousel")
 */
public function SetupInputCarouselAction(Request $request){
    $carousel = new Carousel();
    $form = $this->createForm(CarouselType::class,$carousel);
    $form->handleRequest($request);
    if($form->isSubmitted()){

        //pease rework this in future
        $data = $request->request->get('carousel');
        $carousel->setBildId($data['bildId']);

        $carousel->setText($data['text']);

        if($carousel->getBildId() == -1){
            return $this->redirectToRoute('SetupHome');
        }
        $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
        $em->persist($carousel);
        $em->flush();
    return $this->redirectToRoute('SetupCarousel');

}
```

has anyone any Idea, why this following script do not work? This is the way i can doo it on all other pages in my project.

```
public function SetupInputEventsAction(Request $request){

    //YOU HAVE TO ADD THE ORIGINAL OPTIONS, THIS SOLVE THE PROBLEM
    $repository = $this->getDoctrine()->getRepository("AppBundle:Picture");
    $pictures = $repository->findAll();
    $p = array();
    $p['-- Bitte Bild setzen'] = -1;
    foreach($pictures as $pic){
        /** @var pic Picture */
        $p[$pic->getTitle()] = $pic->getId();
    }
    $carousel = new Carousel();
    $form = $this->createForm(CarouselType::class,$carousel, array(
            'pictures' => $p,
            'action' => $this->generateUrl('SetupInputCarousel')
            ));

    /*
     SEE WORKING ONE ABOVE
     $event = new Carousel();
    $form  = $this->createForm(CarouselType::class,$event);*/
    $form->handleRequest($request);
    if($form->isSubmitted() && $form->isValid()){
        //handel type
        $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
        $em->persist($event);
        $em->flush();
    }
    return $this->redirectToRoute('SetupEvents');
}
```

Friendly Regards,

Fabian Harmsen

Comment: Did you render: `form_widget(form._token)` in the twig template?

Comment: @ĐuroMandinić  this is how i print the form          {{ form_start(form_event) }}
            {{ form_widget(form_event) }}
            {{ form_end(form_event) }}

Comment: Do you get any validation error message? How do you know that the field is not valid?

Comment: @ĐuroMandinić yes there are errors. http://dl.lfs96.de/SymfonyProfiler_2017-04-12.htm here you can see the profiler. I have stopt the redirct so you can ignor the error

Comment: @ĐuroMandinić Problem found and solved

Comment: "SOLVED See last Script. you have to add all options in the form again." — Why is this a question?

Comment: You could post the solution as an answer and accept it so the question doesn't pop up as unanswered.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Soluion is easy you have to add all options to "SetupInputEventsAction" function.

```
public function SetupInputEventsAction(Request $request){

//YOU HAVE TO ADD THE ORIGINAL OPTIONS, THIS SOLVE THE PROBLEM
$repository = $this->getDoctrine()->getRepository("AppBundle:Picture");
$pictures = $repository->findAll();
$p = array();
$p['-- Bitte Bild setzen'] = -1;
foreach($pictures as $pic){
    /** @var pic Picture */
    $p[$pic->getTitle()] = $pic->getId();
}
$carousel = new Carousel();
$form = $this->createForm(CarouselType::class,$carousel, array(
        'pictures' => $p,
        'action' => $this->generateUrl('SetupInputCarousel')
        ));

/*
 SEE WORKING ONE ABOVE
 $event = new Carousel();
$form  = $this->createForm(CarouselType::class,$event);*/
$form->handleRequest($request);
if($form->isSubmitted() && $form->isValid()){
    //handel type
    $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
    $em->persist($event);
    $em->flush();
}
return $this->redirectToRoute('SetupEvents');
}
```

Friendly Regards,

Fabian Harmsen